# vimdiff to operate on only the cursor line

Tags: vimdiff

If I have a block of contiguous flagged lines in vimdiff, then it treats them as if they were a single diff, and pressing 'dp' sets the other buffer the same for the entire block.

Is it possible to have it limit any diff to only the current cursor line?

Comment: Why not just copy paste? It would more easier to do that than try to select the ranges correctly

Comment: @balki Thanks, that's a simpler solution, and when the entire block is correct in one buffer, I can use vimdiff as is to accept the block. Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

Try `v:diffget`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or `v:diffput` <kbd>Enter</kbd>; these are like `do` and `dp` but accept arbitrary ranges. You could probably bind a simple operator pair, too, if you wanted to avoid visual mode.

Comment: I don't understand what 'bind a simple operator pair' means, not that familiar with technical terminology, so did it another way.

Answer (score 0):

On the strength of balki's suggestion above, I now use these 4 mappings

```
nmap <F6>1 yy<Ctrl-w>wddP<Ctrl-w>t]c  " use current cursor line
nmap <F6>2 dp<Ctrl-w>t]c              " use current block
nmap <S-F6>1 <Ctrl-w>w<F6>1           " use other cursor line
nmap <S-F6>2 <Ctrl-w>w<F6>2           " use other block
```